# Why isn't jsonData reading the file?

Tags: reactjs

i have a json file:

```
[ {
  "symbol" : "SPY",
  "type" : "etf"
}, {
  "symbol" : "CMCSA",
  "type" : "stock"
}, {
  "symbol" : "KMI",
  "type" : "stock"
}, {
  "symbol" : "INTC",
  "type" : "stock"
}, {
  "symbol" : "MU",
  "type" : "stock"
},
...
```

And I'm trying to read it into the table:

```
const Home = () =>{
    const displayStockCodes = (info) =>{
        JsonData.map(
            (info)=>{
                return(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{info.symbol}</td>
                        <td>{info.type}</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }
        );
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Symbol</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                    {displayStockCodes}               
                </tbody>
            </table>
             
        </div>

    );
};

export default Home;
```

I tried to do it according to the guide, but in the end only `Symbol` and `Type` are displayed on the page, and the data itself is not output. Maybe I need to add something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `displayStockCodes` is a function but you are not calling it in the `tbody` you need to call that function.
2. `displayStockCodes` also doesn't return anything you need to ensure it returns some `JSX` code.

```
const Home = () =>{
    const displayStockCodes = (info) =>{
        // 2. you need to return 
        return JsonData.map(
            (info)=>{
                return(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{info.symbol}</td>
                        <td>{info.type}</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }
        );
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="table table-striped"> <!-- use className here instead of class -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Symbol</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- you need to call this -->     
                    {displayStockCodes()}               
                </tbody>
            </table>
             
        </div>

    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: no problem. also don't use `class` when writing `JSX`. instead use `className`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Home = () => {
    const JsonData = [
        {
            symbol: 'SPY',
            type: 'etf',
        },
        {
            symbol: 'CMCSA',
            type: 'stock',
        },
        {
            symbol: 'KMI',
            type: 'stock',
        },
        {
            symbol: 'INTC',
            type: 'stock',
        },
        {
            symbol: 'MU',
            type: 'stock',
        },
    ];

    const displayStockCodes = () => {
        return JsonData.map((info) => (
            <tr>
                <td>{info.symbol}</td>
                <td>{info.type}</td>
            </tr>
        ));
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Symbol</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{displayStockCodes()}</tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

The output:

[image]